# How to return html as a string from php for WordPress

Tags: php, plugin-development, shortcode, html

How to return html as a string from php for WordPress

```
function play_audio($atts){
    $a = shortcode_atts( array(
        'url' => ''
    ), $atts );
    wp_enqueue_script('player');
    wp_enqueue_script('play_script');
    wp_enqueue_style('progress_bar');
    return '<div class="mediPlayer">
    <audio class="listen" preload="none" data-size="250" src=" . $a[url] . "></audio>
</div>
</div>';
}
add_shortcode( 'playaudio', 'play_audio' );
```

`src=" . $a[url] . ">` I'm confuse with this part
its not return url

Comment: There's nothing WordPress specific about returning strings. Strings are a basic feature of PHP and work the same everywhere.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are missing multiple single quotes around `$a[url]`, so after `src="` there should be a ' and after `$a[url]` there should be another single quote, and you also need to quote the array key, so the whole return line should be

```
return '<audio class="listen" preload="none" data-size="250" src="' . $a['url'] . '"></audio></div></div>';
```

Comment: its works, but plugin not working javascript error.